# What are the "EMA" weights included with certain pre-trained models?

Tags: machine-learning

I came across this machine learning model called ["Stable Diffusion v1."](https://github.com/CompVis/stable-diffusion) When downloading the [pre-trained weights](https://huggingface.co/CompVis/stable-diffusion-v-1-4-original) for this model, I noticed that there's a couple of different files:

- `sd-v1-4.ckpt`
- `sd-v1-4-full-ema.ckpt`

How do I know which file I want, and why does it matter? What is "full EMA" regarding weights?

[image]

Comment: QUOTE: From what I understand, 'sd-v1-4_ckpt' contains just the weights and
 biases for inference. 'sd-v1-4-full-ema_ckpt' contains the weights and
 biases + momentum and other training related metadata, so you could
 continue the training steps. ( https://huggingface.co/CompVis/stable-diffusion-v-1-4-original/discussions/7 )

At the moment the source also contains a link to a video that shows EMA and non-EMA weights difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a late answer, but I couldn't let this question go unanswered.

The difference between the two files is likely related to the use of Exponential Moving Average (EMA) in training.

The file `sd-v1-4.ckpt` contains the standard trained weights of the model. While the file `sd-v1-4-full-ema.ckpt` contains the weights of the model where EMA has been applied. EMA is a technique used during training to stabilize and improve the generalization of the model. It's a running average of the model's parameters, and using the EMA weights during inference can often lead to better results.

In many cases, the EMA weights are used during the evaluation or testing phase because they can provide more stable and well-generalized predictions. However, during training, the standard weights are updated more frequently to follow the current training data more closely.

Which file to use? it depends on your use case:

- If you are fine-tuning the model or using it for further training, you might want to use the standard weights `sd-v1-4.ckpt`.
- If you are using the model for inference or evaluation, the weights with EMA applied `sd-v1-4-full-ema.ckpt` might give you more stable and reliable results.

In many cases, people choose to use EMA weights for tasks like generating samples or making predictions because they can help reduce the impact of noisy updates that might occur during training.